# For loop not looping through args

Tags: args

I'm typing in this code verbatim for a class, but it's not working. I'm using Python3.7. It never moves past the first argument. What is wrong?

```
#function with variable number of arguments
def multi_add(*args):
    result = 0
    for x in args:
        result = result + x
        return result

print (multi_add(10, 4, 5))
```

Comment: You `return` as soon as you process the first arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `return result` has incorrect indentation. As it is i would expect it to return after first arg, wheras if it were one indent left it would return after forloop completes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing it this way.

```py
#function with variable number of arguments
def multi_add(*args):
    result = 0
    for x in args:
        result = result + x
        print(result)

multi_add(10,4,5)
```